# How do I get the network name from an IRC server?

Tags: networking, irc

I didn't think this was possible, but mIRC can get the name of a network, even if it is not specified by the user in the server list. I tried using a packet sniffer to see if perhaps there was a message sent on connect that sends the network's name, but I didn't see anything.

The network name is needed to display to the user as well as determine if multiple servers are part of the same network. I'm hoping this is a problem someone else has already solved.

Answer (score 5):

On connect (or receipt of the `VERSION` protocol command), the server may send back one or more `005` numerics.

These numerics carry multiple `Name=Value` pairs, one of which may be `NETWORK=<network name>`.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://www.irc.org/tech_docs/draft-brocklesby-irc-isupport-03.txt

Answer (score -1):

I don't see anything in [RFC 1459](http://www.irchelp.org/irchelp/text/rfc1459.txt) about it.  Now, that doesn't mean a server here and there doesn't implement a particular command to get this information, but I don't think there is a reliable way to do so.

Answer (score -1):

You only have to type the following into your irc client

//echo $network

Comment: Thank you but this is not what I was asking.